# ORTools - vehicle routing - minimize package time en route

Tags: or-tools, vehicle-routing

I am creating solution for vehicle routing with pickup and deliveries. My objective is to minimize time that each packages is being transported (the domain is food delivery and we wont to make the time between the food preparation and it's delivery as short as possible). My idea was to create a variable for each pickup-delivery pair and tell the routing to minimize it:

```
solver = routing.solver()

diff = solver.IntVar(0, MAX_TIMESTAMP_VALUE, f'diff_{pickup_node}_{delivery_node}')
solver.Add(diff == time_dimension.CumulVar(delivery_index) - time_dimension.CumulVar(pickup_index))

routing.AddWeightedVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(diff, 1)
```

Unfortunately this does not work - it seems that the solver completly ignores this objective and produces the same solution as without it. Could someone advise me, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is not an objective.
A finalizer just tells the solver it needs to fix this extra variable, and indicates in which direction it needs to branch.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, could you give me a hint then, how to formulate such objective with OR -tools?